# How to format and print multiple strings in Java

Tags: java, string

When outputting first and last, it combines them both. How would I go about making `First` and `Last` be outputted separately. I also tried add an output for the total number of characters would I declare it after the string is declared or after the `Out.print` it declared?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Lab2
{
    public static void main(String[] args) //header of the main method
    {
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        String First;
        String Last;

        System.out.println("Enter you First name");
        First = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter you Last name");
        Last = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println((First) + (Last));
```

Comment: Also, names of variables must start with a lower-case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.format`:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%s %s", First, Last));
```

Alternatively, you can just add a space there manually:

```
System.out.println(First + ' ' + Last);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(First + " " + Last);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the whitespace manually:

```
System.out.print(First + “ “ + Last);
```

Or maybe print it in different lines using “\n” :

```
System.out.print(First + “\n” + Last);
```

As for declaring your variables, it is best practice to declare them right after the class when possible:

```
class Lab2{
String First;
String Last;
int charCount;

public static void main(String[] args){
//code
  }
}
```

Though you can also declare it inside the method in this case.

To get the amount of characters you must initialize the variable that will store it **after** getting the input from the scanner so your code should look something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Lab2
{

String First;
String Last;
int charCount;

    public static void main(String[] args) //header of the main method
    {
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter you First name");
        First = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter you Last name");
        Last = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println((First) + (Last));

        charCount = First.length() + Last.length();
        System.out.println(“Total number of characters = “ + charCount);
   }
}
```

If you are working with bigger strings that may have whitespace or input with leading/trailing spaces, there are a lot of useful methods like String.trim() and String.strip() you can find more reference here:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-string-trim-method-example/
https://howtodoinjava.com/java11/strip-remove-white-spaces/